# Android Studio Error Type 3: Error while Launching activity

Tags: android-studio

I am new to android development and I really find it all messy and confusing at times. I was running My project which worked alright before then Copied an activity and changed the package name which worked fine. I closed the android studio. Now when I opened my project again I started getting the error "Error while launching:: No default Activity found" but I had it in AndroidManifest.xml. Then I tried the "Edit Configuration-> General ->Launch app and set it to Splashscreen. Now I am getting this new error which is too stubborn to disappear ! I have tried everything  but nothing really worked for me. Kindly help me out I may be missing something stupid.

```
 $ adb shell am start -n"com.example.dell.optasiaapp/com.example.dell.optasiaapp.Splashscreen" -a     android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
 Error while executing: am start -n    "com.example.dell.optasiaapp/com.example.dell.optasiaapp.Splashscreen" -a   android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=    [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.dell.optasiaapp/.Splashscreen }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.dell.optasiaapp/com.example.dell.optasiaapp.Splashscreen} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

What I have tried:

- Clean project and rebuild
- Uninstalling app, disconnecting the mobile and reconnecting to build again
- Deleting.idea/workspace.xml
- adding Application id = "Pakage name" in gradle build
- Changing android:name=".Splashscreen" to  android:name="com.example.dell.optasiaapp.Splashscreen"
- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

My AndroidManifest code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
<activity android:name=".Splashscreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".HomeScreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.dell.optasiaapp.HomeScreen" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity android:name=".AboutUs">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.dell.optasiaapp.AboutUs" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.About" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Help" >        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is so stupid. I tried everything available on Internet but nothing worked for me. So I just made a new project and copy pasted every code to the new empty activities. It runs fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the package name manually, try this:
In build.gradle change 
apply plugin: 'android-library'
to
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Answer (score 0):

One of the worst things that I have faced in Android Studio.

Follow following steps:

1. Close your Android Studio.
2. Delete .idea/workspace.xml
3. Launch Android Studio and launch your application.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, emulating the app and trying in other phones worked perfect, only with my phone was failing.

Something that work for me was deleting all other user profiles, including the guest user.